# How to check if there is a message after a command discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to edit my code so it checks if there is any string after the discord.py command, here is what it looks like.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def dankrate(ctx, *, message):
    message_author = ctx.author
    message_channel = ctx.channel
    
    print(message)
    
    aaaaa = random.randint(1, 101)
    print("{} issued .dankrate ".format(message_author))
    
    if aaaaa == 101:
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Dank r8 Machine", description=f"you broke the dank machine >:( :fire:\n{message} is {aaaaa}% dank", color=15105570)
    else:
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Dank r8 Machine", description=f"{message} is {aaaaa}% dank", color=3066993)
    await message_channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

it works as it is intended but when you run the dankrate command **with** a string, such as ".dankrate e" but if you run the command without a string after the command, it returns with
`discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: message is a required argument that is missing.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are mainly 2 ways of doing this and `pass_context` is not needed in discord.py rewrite**

```py
@client.command()
async def dankrate(ctx, *, message=None):
    if not message: #nothing is passed after the command
        return await ctx.send("**Please pass in required arguments**")
    message_author = ctx.author
    message_channel = ctx.channel
    
    print(message)
    
    aaaaa = random.randint(1, 101)
    print("{} issued .dankrate ".format(message_author))
    
    if aaaaa == 101:
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Dank r8 Machine", description=f"you broke the dank machine >:( :fire:\n{message} is {aaaaa}% dank", color=15105570)
    else:
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Dank r8 Machine", description=f"{message} is {aaaaa}% dank", color=3066993)
    await message_channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

OR

```py
@client.command()
async def dankrate(ctx, *, message):
    message_author = ctx.author
    message_channel = ctx.channel
    
    print(message)
    
    aaaaa = random.randint(1, 101)
    print("{} issued .dankrate ".format(message_author))
    
    if aaaaa == 101:
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Dank r8 Machine", description=f"you broke the dank machine >:( :fire:\n{message} is {aaaaa}% dank", color=15105570)
    else:
        embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Dank r8 Machine", description=f"{message} is {aaaaa}% dank", color=3066993)
    await message_channel.send(embed=embedVar)

@dankrate.error
async def dankrate_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        return await ctx.send("**Please pass in required arguments**")
    else:
        raise(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a decorator of Discordpy that allows you check things before execute the command:

```
def check_if_it_is_owner(ctx):
    return ctx.message.author.id == OWNER_ID

@bot.command()
@commands.check(check_if_it_is_owner)
async def only_the_cool_guy(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Super user command execution')
```

More info: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#checks